# Flutter use multiple Stateful widget from separate files in another

Tags: flutter, dart

I've separated widgets for my coloring app into into different files.

here's a rough presentation of the widget tree that I intend to work on. I want to use `menu_items.dart` in `PaintingScreen.dart` and `menu_items.dart` will contain

1. `color_palette.dart`
2. `stroke_picker.dart`
3. `stroke_picker.dart`

[image]

Since it's a coloring app users will be able to change color provided in `color_palette` and `stroke width`, `opacity`

Unfortunately as soon as I separated my widgets into different files I can't update my values for opacity, stroke width, opacity.

Here's my `color_palette.dart`:

```
class ColorPalette extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ColorPaletteState createState() => _ColorPaletteState();
}

class _ColorPaletteState extends State<ColorPalette> {
  Color selectedColor = Colors.black;
  Color pickerColor = Color(0xff443a49);
  Color currentColor = Color(0xff443a49);

  void changeColor(Color color) {
    setState(() => selectedColor = color);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: BlockPicker(pickerColor: pickerColor, onColorChanged: changeColor),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my `opacity_picker.dart`

```
class OpacityPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OpacityPickerState createState() => _OpacityPickerState();
}

class _OpacityPickerState extends State<OpacityPicker> {
  double opacity = 1.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              opacity = 0.1;
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 20),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              opacity = 0.5;
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 30),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              opacity = 1.0;
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.opacity, size: 40),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Both of this widgets will be used in `menu_items.dart`

```
class UtilityItems extends StatefulWidget {
  final double opacity;
  final double strokeWidth;

  UtilityItems({@required this.opacity, @required this.strokeWidth});
  @override
  _UtilityItemsState createState() => _UtilityItemsState();
}

class _UtilityItemsState extends State<UtilityItems> {
  List<TouchPoints> points = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            StrokePicker(),
            OpacityPicker(),
            ColorPalette(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now in PaintingScreen.dart there are a few places I want to use items from `menu_items.dart`:

inside **gesture detector**:

```
onPanUpdate: (details) {
   setState(() {
      RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
      points.add(TouchPoints(
         points: renderBox.globalToLocal(
              details.globalPosition),
              paint: Paint()
                  ..strokeCap = strokeType
                  ..isAntiAlias = true
                  ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                  ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
       });
},
```

And inside an **Expanded**:

```
Expanded(
  flex: 2,
  child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.grey,
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
             Radius.circular(20),
         ),
      ),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
      child: UtilityItems(
         opacity: opacity, strokeWidth: strokeWidth),
      ),
),
```

UtilityItems from `menu_items.dart` is showing everything except updating the values. Can anyone explain why the values are not getting updated? And  what I should implement in order to make it work?

Comment: Use riverpod/provider as state mang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your other widgets are not aware when the user selects a color using your `ColorPalette` widget. This is because the color he chooses is stored only in the `ColorPalette` widget. To solve this, we need a way to let any of the other widgets store/change/read the color value that is set by the user.

A simple way to achieve this is to use [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/). It will let you create a `Color` variable that can be accessed from any widget. Take a look at this [counter example](https://github.com/rrousselGit/river_pod/blob/master/examples/counter/lib/main.dart). The `counter` is being updated by a widget, and then it is read by another widget.

Comment: so `final strokeWidthProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 3.0);` should be inside `menu_items.dart`?